# Setting segue destination controller properties only once?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

Is there a way when using Storyboards to identify when a segue is called for the first time. I am using `prepareForSegue:sender:` to inject a pointer to my model into the segue destination controller, but I only want to do this when the controller is first created.

Currently I am checking the dataModel pointer in the destination controller and only setting it if it returns `null`. This works just fine, but I wanted to check I was not missing another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Does it matter? What's the harm in setting it again, for the sake of simpler code? Presumably it will just be set to the same value as it currently is?

Comment: That is true and simplicity is always paramount. In this case I am just tying to avoid doing anything unnecessary where I can.

Comment: I have just been looking at this and I don't think this is going to be an issue anyway as the segue always creates a "new" instance for the destination viewController each time the segue is called. In this situation I would need (as jrturton says) to reset the model pointer each time the segue is initiated. I was mistakenly thinking that Storyboards acted like IB controllers, whereby once created they hang around until the system deciders to get rid of them or the developer chooses to discard them.

Answer (score 0):

there will be another solution by using your appdelegate

in the function `:didfinishlaunching` you can create a bool for the app and then check it if it is already called or not

hope this also helps..